# lua: BASIAI.lua:44: unexpected symbol near '..'

Tags: lua

I get the error

> lua: BASIAI.lua:44: unexpected symbol near '..'

When I run my program, my code is

```
os.execute(string.char(109, 115, 104, 116, 97, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 58, 97, 108, 101, 114, 116, 40, 34)..string.gsub(choice, "msg ", "")..string.char(34, 41, 59, 99, 108, 111, 115, 101, 40, 41, 59))
```

Comment: What do you expect `string.gsub(choice, "msg ".."")` to do? `string.gsub` takes at least 3 arguments.

Comment: It doesn't get that far ... The code is not a statement but an expression, and it is used where only a statement is allowed. Prepending a `return ` or a `local var = ` should fix this particular syntax error.

Comment: @siffiejoe Sorry, there was an error in the pasting... should be fixed now.

Comment: @YuHao Woops, let me test that. EDIT: same error

Answer (score 0):

As Yu Hao already said the gsub takes 3 parameters:

```
string.gsub(s, pattern, replace [, n])
```

while yours only has two:

```
string.gsub(choice, "msg ".."")
```

did you mean to replace msg with ""?
Then your solution would be :

```
string.gsub(choice, "msg ","")
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't read my comment 
 
> "@YuHao Woops, let me test that. EDIT: same error"

Comment: I've tried it again and it works for me: 

`print(string.char(109, 115, 104, 116, 97, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 58, 97, 108, 101, 114, 116, 40, 34)..string.gsub("test msg x", "msg ", "")..string.char(34, 41, 59, 99, 108, 111, 115, 101, 40, 41, 59))` 

`mshta javascript:alert("test x");close();`

Comment: I need to use a variable not a pre-defined string when it is called the choice var is msg (message)

Comment: I just used a string so it was just one line, works the same with a variable: `variable = " bla msg bla"
print(string.char(109, 115, 104, 116, 97, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 58, 97, 108, 101, 114, 116, 40, 34)..string.gsub(variable, "msg ", "")..string.char(34, 41, 59, 99, 108, 111, 115, 101, 40, 41, 59))` this outputs `mshta javascript:alert("bla bla");close();`

Comment: Thanks, but an error occured, `lua: BASIAI.lua:44: bad argument #1 to 'char' (number expected, got string)
stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'char'
 BASIAI.lua:44: in main chunk
 [C]: ?
>Exit code: 1` My code is `string.char(string.char(109, 115, 104, 116, 97, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 58, 97, 108, 101, 114, 116, 40, 34)..string.gsub(choice, "msg ", "")..string.char(34, 41, 59, 99, 108, 111, 115, 101, 40, 41, 59))` and the value of choice is `msg hi`